# Headphones always muted after restart

Tags: audio, alsa, pulseaudio

After system restart my headphones are always muted. I have to unmute and crank volume from 0% to 100% using alsamixer. I of course tried to do alsactl store multiple times but it does not help. It is not the case though with speakers. They are always unmuted and on 100% of volume.

I am using Fedora 21 and it uses pulseaudio by default -- I am not able to disable it because it is started every time I start kde4.

Comment: I've uninstalled brain dead piece of #$%! called pulseaudio and problem dissapeared.

Answer (score 0):

To tell pulseaudio that headphones are always plugged in. Edit:

/usr/share/pulseaudio/alsa-mixer/paths/analog-output-lineout.conf

FIND:

```
[Jack Headphone]

state.plugged = no (--->Change no to yes)

state.unplugged = unknown
```

OR/AND:

```
[Jack Front Headphone]
state.plugged = no (--->Change no to yes)
state.unplugged = unknown
```

AND:

```
[Element Headphone]
switch = off (--->Change off to on)
volume = off
```

OR/AND:

```
[Element Headphone2]
switch = off (--->Change off to on)
volume = off
```

SAVE FILE AND restart pulseaudio:

```
$ pulseaudio -k
$ pulseaudio --start
```